# Find elements by attribute name containing colon

Tags: java, selenium

## Java automation with selenium and TestNG

I am automating a web page which contains an svg #document object.
The page contains controls to toggle layers of the svg document on and off.

I have hashmapped the controls to their labels just fine for use in my tests, and i intend to test the layer controls by verifying that after each layer is turned on, the elements in that layer are displayed (and vice versa for turning each layer off).

The best way i can think of to do this, is to iteratively add each element to a List. 
The result would effectively be:
list1 contains all layer1 elements,
list2 contains all layer2 elements,
list3 contains all layer3 elements.

The only thing as far as i can tell that is common across each element in its respective layer, is an attribute called "v:layerMember". Each Layer's         "v:layerMember" attribute has a different value, so distinguishing between the elements in each layer is not a problem.
I would identify each layer's elements like so:

```
layer1 = driver.findElements(By.something("v:layerMember=0"));
layer2 = driver.findElements(By.something("v:layerMember=15"));
layer3 = driver.findElements(By.something("v:layerMember=16"));
```

OR

```
@FindBy(something="v:layerMember='0'")
List layer1;

@FindBy(something="v:layerMember='15'")
List layer2;

@FindBy(something="v:layerMember='16'")
List layer3;
```

### Problem:

I've tried finding each set of layer elements by xpath, css, and even JQuery. No matter what, each one always returns an empty list.
I have had success by finding each element by id, but since there are over 35 of them, it's a bit impractical going forward.
Is it even possible to find by attribute name containing ":" character?

Need some help here.

## EDIT:

I figured out a way to do what i wanted to do. It's not very performant, and it's a bit gross, but i think it will do the trick until i have time to find a better way.

Note: It's in js atm because i was fiddling with the html doc. Should be easy to translate to Java though.

```
function getElementsByAttributeContains(attrSubString) {
    var refinedList = [];
    var baseList = document.querySelectorAll('g[style]');

    for (var i = 0; i < baseList.length; i++) {
        if (baseList[i].outerHTML.toString().search(attrSubString) != -1) {
            refinedList.push(baseList[i]);
        }   
    }
    for(var j = 0; j < refinedList.length; j++) {
        if (refinedList[j].getAttribute('style').search("transform") != -1){
            refinedList.splice(j, 1);
            j = j - 1;
        }
    }
    return refinedList;
};
```

Comment: Would you please post a link to the page or some of the relevant HTML? I would like to have a sample page to try some code against.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't do that due to the nature of the product under test.

Comment: @dozzamike Could you atleast post the structure of one of the elements you are trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

Using `cssSelector` and `xpath` you need to put square brackets around the attribute

```
layer1 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[v:layerMember='0']"));
```